# How do I make the center of rotation of this '::before' pseudoelement change?

Tags: html, css, animation, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I'm trying to make an animated border for a div. I unhid the overflow of its formatting element so that I could see what the issue was. I'd like to make the center of rotation the center of the larger div.

I know I can make the center of rotation higher by setting the width and height of the before psuedoelement to that of its container, but I want to make it taller because if I set the width and height to its formatting element, it's too small and doesn't cover the edges.

I've tried using CSS positioning, but it isn't working and I have no idea why.

```
        <div class="center">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="directory module">
                <div id="header" class="small_wrapper center">
                    <div class="module">
                        <p style="font-size: 22px">Placeholder</p>
                      </div>
                </div>
                <div class="directory_bar small_wrapper center"><div class="module">About Me</div></div>
                <div class="directory_bar small_wrapper center"><div class="module">PC Builds</div></div>
                <div class="directory_bar small_wrapper center"><div class="module">Original Characters</div></div>
                <div class="directory_bar small_wrapper center"><div class="module">Games & Loadouts</div></div>
                <div class="directory_bar small_wrapper center"><div class="module">Socials</div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


@charset "utf-8";
    
@keyframes rotate {
    0% {
      transform: rotate(0);
    }

    50% {
        transform: rotate(180deg);
    }

    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}



html {
    font-size: 3.0vh;
}

body {
    background-color: #2C2C2C;
    font-family: Urbanist, sans serif;
    color: white;
}

p {
    margin: 0;
}



.left, .right, .center {
    position: relative;
}

.center {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.module {
    background-color:#2C2C2C;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;

    border-radius: 18px;
    z-index: 1000;
    position: relative;
}

.wrapper, .small_wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: fit-content;
    height: fit-content;
    background: blue;
    z-index: 1000;

    
}

.wrapper {
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 4px;
}

.wrapper::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left:  0;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(255, 0, 0), rgb(145, 
    255, 0), rgb(189, 1, 180));
    animation: rotate;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    content: '';
    border-radius: 20px;
    height: 1000px;

}


.small_wrapper {
    padding: 3px;
}

.directory_bar {
    margin-top: 5vh;
}

.directory {
    padding: 5vh;
}

.center > .wrapper {
    margin-left: 100px;
}

.directory_bar, #header {
    border-radius: 8px;
}

.directory_bar > .module, #header > .module {
    border-radius: 7px;
}
```

Comment: Have you invesigated transform-origin?